# How much ketchup is on the table? (Ketchup flow rate problem)

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, physics, word-problem

This is a question I came up with while watching my friend squirt ketchup onto his table. He was squirting the ketchup out of a bottle while moving the bottle upwards.

A ketchup bottle starts upside down with the tip at the table. Ketchup is squirted out at a volume flow rate of $Q(t)$, in $\frac{m^3}{s}$, while the bottle itself is moving upwards at a rate of $v(t$), in $\frac{m}{s}$.

When the ketchup comes out of the bottle it is always initially not moving, but immediately starts falling to the table due to gravity ($g = 10 \frac{m}{s^2}$ downwards).

Find $V(t)$, the volume of ketchup on the table as a function of time.

Edit 1: We can **ignore** the fact that in real life the accumulating ketchup on the table will, in some sense, increase the height of the table.

[image]

Comment: Thumbs up because of the bizarreness of your question :)

Comment: +1 for the graphics!

Comment: I'd like to thank your friend for inspiring this absurd question.

Comment: Are you having to squeeze the bottle or is it flowing out naturally?

Comment: To simplify, are we ignoring the increasing height of the ketchup as the volume increases?

Comment: Or do we assume that the ketchup forms a cylinder with a changing radius? Helps to simplify things.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan, right, having a known geometry would be fine.  Although, I'm not sure that any given geometry is much more accurate than assuming no height...

Comment: @Carser Hi! I have made an edit to the question. We can ignore the increasing height of the ketchup on the table.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan As far as I know it shouldn't matter whether the ketchup bottle is being squeezed or it is naturally flowing out. In real life, that might affect the volume flow rate, Q(t), but here Q(t) is a given function. It is also given that the ketchup coming directly out of the bottle starts a rest. :)

Comment: When the ketchup comes out of the bottle it still has velocity $v(t)$ upwards. Think of a  space ship starting vertically upwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we let $x=0$ be the table top and measure upwards, the bottle position is $x(t)=vt$.
Ketchup that leaves the bottle at time $t$ takes $t'$ to fall where $vt=\frac 12g(t')^2$
Ketchup that leaves the bottle at time $t$ hits the table at $t+\sqrt{\frac {2vt}g}$
At time $u$ the ketchup that just arrived at the table left the bottle at time $t$ where $u=t+\sqrt{\frac {2vt}g}$
We would like to invert this equation
$$u=t+\sqrt{\frac {2vt}g}\\(u-t)^2=\frac {2vt}g\\t^2-2ut-\frac {2v}gt+u^2=0\\
t=\frac 12\left(2u+\frac {2v}g-\sqrt{(2u+\frac {2v}g)^2-4u^2}\right)$$
and the amount of ketchup at time $u$ is $Q$ times this.  If $Q$ is not a constant, you need to integrate
$$\int_0^{t(u)}Q(t)dt$$to get the amount on the table at time $u$

Comment: This seems to be for a constant velocity $v(t)$, I think.  What about when $v(t)$ is not constant?

Comment: @Carser:  yes, I assumed constant $v$.  If $v$ is not constant the same logic works.  You need to look back in time to the time when the bottle was as a height that the ketchup that left is just hitting the table.  If $v(t)$ is not simple you will have to find a numeric solution.